# Retrieving Packaged Page Layout in Apex

Tags: apex, page-layout, metadata

So using the spanking new meta data in Apex you can get page layout information (at last!):

```
List<String> componentNameList = new List<String>{'Opportunity-Opportunity Layout'};
List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, componentNameList);

layout = (Metadata.Layout) components.get(0);
System.debug(layout);
```

Yes, the above code is nasty but it works. What doesn't work is getting a page layout from our managed package. Everything I can find suggests that it simply needs the standard `namespace__` in front of the object:

```
List<String> componentNameList = new List<String>{'PRX__Transaction__c-Transaction Layout'};
```

But that's not returning anything and I have confirmed the layout name via MavensMate:

[image: MavensMate screenshot showing layout name as PRX__Transaction__c-Transaction Layout]

What am I missing here? The checkbox to allow packages to update metadata is checked (tried both ways) but there's nothing else I can think of to check.

Comment: The example in the [Metadata Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm) seems to concur as they use `'ISVNamespace__TestCustomMDType.MyTestCustomMDType'`

Comment: Maybe also try Aaron Slettehaugh via the [Apex Metadata API](https://success.salesforce.com/0F930000000PbSh) success group?

Comment: Yeah I might have to. I really wish they'd remove the SSO on that, you can guarantee I'll have yet another new profile by the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for `Metadata.Operations` class are the same as the rules for `Metadata API`, so answer [from these question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13852/how-to-retrieve-layouts-of-customs-objects-belonging-to-a-managed-package)[s](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139472/how-to-fetch-a-layout-from-metadata-api-in-apex-under-a-name-prefix) worked well for me, you just need to double prefix the namespace in format 
`<namespace>__<Object Name>-<namespace>__<Layout Name>`

So this code works fine for me

```
List<String> componentNameList = new List<String>{'PRX__Transaction__c-PRX__Transaction Layout'};
List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, componentNameList);

Metadata.Layout layout = (Metadata.Layout) components.get(0);
System.debug(layout);
```

Comment: That's the problem, it wasn't working in this situation.

Comment: it  is because you tried new List<String>{'PRX__Transaction__c-Transaction Layout'}; but most probably haven't tried new List<String>{'PRX__Transaction__c-PRX__Transaction Layout'};

Comment: Oh my bad, I missed that second use of the prefix. I'll give it a go and see what happens!

Comment: I wonder if this would work for you since double prefixing works perfect for me