# Retrieve Page Layout using Metadata.Operations.retrieve

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

I have seen the answer to this post: [Retrieving Packaged Page Layout in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187706/retrieving-packaged-page-layout-in-apex) 
I am using the same code with my values substituted:

```
List<String> componentNameList = new List<String>{'MyNamespace__Transaction__c-MyNameSpace__Transaction Layout'};
List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, componentNameList);
Metadata.Layout layout = (Metadata.Layout) components.get(0);
System.debug(layout);
```

I can retrieve a Page Layout for Standard sObjects like Account and Opportunity.
I can retrieve a Page Layout for a Managed Object for a Page Layout that was included with the Package.
Where I am hitting an issue is retrieving a Page Layout for the same Managed object and a Layout that was created custom in the SFDC Org.

My Page Layout Name on the Managed sObject from workbench is 'MyCustom Layout'.
I have tried using 'MyNamespace__Transaction__c-MyNameSpace__MyCustom Layout' and 'MyNamespace__Transaction__c-MyCustom Layout' as the value to retrieve the metadata but neither works.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to retrieve a Custom Page Layout from a Managed sObject?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ManagedPackageNameSpace__CustomObject__c-MyNamespace__MyCustom Layout` to retrive custom layout for a managed object.

Comment: I tried that also and the page layout was not retrieved. It appears to be a bug.

Comment: Can you please text here, what exactly you have tried?

Comment: @myForceDotCom Are you trying to get the layout from a dev org where your installed the managed package and your page layout is created locally (not with the namespace) or are you working on a namespaced scratch org?

Comment: I am working in a Production Org with the managed Package installed.

Comment: This code returns the Managed Page Layout:
componentNameList.add('litify_pm__Matter__c-litify_pm__Matter Layout v3');

These do not. PersonalNuggets is the Custom Page Layout created custom in the org.
componentNameList.add('litify_pm__Matter__c-PersonalNuggets');
componentNameList.add('litify_pm__Matter__c-litify_pm__PersonalNuggets');

Comment: production org's namespace is litify_pm?

Comment: You shouldn't need the namespace for custom created layout so, `litify_pm__Matter__c-PersonalNuggets` should work. Can you see any issues in the logs? If it's not working probably raise a case with Salesforce? @myForceDotCom

Comment: Logs show nothing unusual. Must be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

After countless variations it appears to be a known issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008fw0QAA&title=unable-to-retrieve-unmanaged-layout-of-managed-object-via-metadate-api